# Has Krishna said explicitly how to measure spiritual advancement?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, spiritual-level

One *sloka* I personally like refer to in order to remind me of spiritual advancement is in the [Bhagavad-Gita 2.56](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/2/56).

> duḥkheṣv anudvigna-manāḥ
>
> sukheṣu vigata-spṛhaḥ
>
> vīta-rāga-bhaya-krodhaḥ
>
> sthita-dhīr munir ucyate

Word for word:

> duḥkheṣu — in the threefold miseries; anudvigna-manāḥ — without being
> agitated in mind; sukheṣu — in happiness; vigata-spṛhaḥ — without
> being interested; vīta — free from; rāga — attachment; bhaya — fear;
> krodhaḥ — and anger; sthita-dhīḥ — whose mind is steady; muniḥ — a
> sage; ucyate — is called.

Translation:

> One who is not disturbed in mind even amidst the threefold miseries or
> elated when there is happiness, and who is free from attachment, fear
> and anger, is called a sage of steady mind.

Is there any passage(s) where Krishna states what is/how to measure spiritual advancement?

Comment: @Pandya haha, no, I mean the closer a person is to their true nature (spirit), detachment from the material world, and pleasure in the spiritual things, for example

Comment: Well, continue reading the next verses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recension of the Gita commented on by Sankara has this as verse 2.55. In his commentary on this verse, Sankara says (Swami Gambhirananda translator):

> In the verses beginning from 'When one fully renounces...', and ending with the completion the Chapter, instruction about the characteristics of the man of steady wisdom and the disciplines (he has passed through) is being given both for the one who has, indeed, applied himself to steadfastness in the Yoga of Knowledge after having renounced rites and duties form the beginning (even while in the stage of celibacy), and for the one who has (applied himself to this after having passed) through the path of Karma-yoga. For in all the scriptures without exception, dealing with spirituality, whatever are the characteristics of the man of realization are themselves presented as the disciplines for an aspirant, because these (characteristics) are the result of effort. And those that are the disciplines requiring effort, they become the characteristics (of the man of realization).

your answer is in the subsequent verses of chapter 2.